# Prevent Edge desktop shortcut on new profiles

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1803

I'm working on a new template image using Windows 10 1803 for my company. I noticed the Edge browser is putting a desktop shortcut on new profiles.

The shortcut is not present in the default profile (`c:\users\Default\Desktop`) or the All Users profile (`C:\Users\Public\Desktop`).

I allow a shortcut for edge to be pinned to the start menu and taskbar. I don't need or want any icons (at all!  ...curse you, Recycle Bin) on our default desktop. Where is this shortcut coming from, and how can I stop it?

Comment: A pretty common problem lately. Have a look at [this](https://www.joseespitia.com/2018/05/11/how-to-prevent-the-edge-shortcut-from-appearing-on-a-desktop-after-the-windows-10-1803-upgrade/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears the behavior is intentional.  You can disable it by modifying the registry as explained below.

> During my early testing of the Windows 10 1803 upgrade, I have noticed that Microsoft is now creating an Edge shortcut on the desktop.
>
> This shortcut is not in the default profile but you can disable the functionality by running the following command:
>
> `reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer /v "DisableEdgeDesktopShortcutCreation" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f`
>
> [Jose Espitia](https://www.joseespitia.com/2018/05/11/how-to-prevent-the-edge-shortcut-from-appearing-on-a-desktop-after-the-windows-10-1803-upgrade/)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Do you have any information, you can provide us, written by Microsoft that confirms that fact?   I believe words are important, and I am focused on a word I hate "might",  I try to avoid information that "might" be true in my answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PowerShell also:

```
$registrypath = "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer"
$name = "DisableEdgeDesktopShortcutCreation"
$value = "1"
New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType DWORD -Force | Out-Null
```

Answer (score -3):

I just dropped the shortcut into a new folder, and dropped the whole folder into recycle bin. That removed it for good without adjusting a REG.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  This Question is geared towards preventing the shortcut from being created at all, for instance on a fleet of 500 company Windows PCs, so that users, especially executives, don't have to see the icon ever.  The shortcut could also be deleted via script, but it would be visible for a short time, prompting questions from nervous executives.